# python dict() initialisation

Tags: python, dictionary

Since a few weeks I am learning Python. I have a background in C++, which might explain the question.

It is about the following python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class testA:
    dictionary = dict()

    def __init__(self):
        pass


class testB:
    dictionary = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary = dict()


def main():
    ta1 = testA()
    ta2 = testA()
    tb1 = testB()
    tb2 = testB()

    ta1.dictionary["test1"] = 1
    ta1.dictionary["test2"] = 2
    ta2.dictionary["test3"] = 3
    ta2.dictionary["test4"] = 4

    print "testA ta1"
    for key in ta1.dictionary.keys():
        print "  " + key + "\t" + str(ta1.dictionary[key])
    print "testA ta2"
    for key in ta2.dictionary.keys():
        print "  " + key + "\t" + str(ta2.dictionary[key])


    tb1.dictionary["test1"] = 1
    tb1.dictionary["test2"] = 2
    tb2.dictionary["test3"] = 3
    tb2.dictionary["test4"] = 4

    print "testB tb1"
    for key in tb1.dictionary.keys():
        print "  " + key + "\t" + str(tb1.dictionary[key])
    print "testB tb2"
    for key in tb2.dictionary.keys():
        print "  " + key + "\t" + str(tb2.dictionary[key])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output of this code is:

```
$ python2 pytest.py 
testA ta1
  test1 1
  test3 3
  test2 2
  test4 4
testA ta2
  test1 1
  test3 3
  test2 2
  test4 4
testB tb1
  test1 1
  test2 2
testB tb2
  test3 3
  test4 4
```

However, I do not understand why the dictionaries in ta1 and ta2 are the same. What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Note that in the TestB class, the `dictionary = None` in the class is misleading because it's shadowed by the `self.dictionary = dict()` in the init function (ob.dictionary will always find the instance's dictionary, so the class' dictionary is never used). It should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dictionary` attribute of `TestA` belongs to the class and not to its instances. That is the reason why all instances of `TestA` look the same. You should do this:

```
class TestA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary = dict() # this will make dictionary belong to the instance, and each instance will get its own copy of dictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

In class `testA` the attribute `dictionary` is an attribute of the class, not of the object (like a static attribute in `C++`). So it is shared by all `testA` instances. If you want to add the attribute to an object `A` you have to write something like `A.attr`, or `self.attr` somewhere where `self` is defined that is inside a method. Clearly, unless you have a good reason for not doing so, `__init__` is the right place for that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is plain and simple:  That dictionary (there is only one) is created when the class is created.  Each instance will share that dict.

If you want one dict to be created for each instance, so it in the `__init__()` method.